# Data Structures/Records

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

My current program looks like this. This program should ask 5 records of a person and display them.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct rec {
    char name[100],address[100];
    double age,mobileno;
}x;

main()
{
    int i;
    clrscr();

    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Your Name: ");
        scanf("%s",&x.name);

        printf("Enter Your Age: ");
        scanf("%lf",&x.age);

        printf("Enter Your Address: ");
        scanf("%s",&x.address);

        printf("Enter Your Mobile No.: ");
        scanf("%lf",&x.mobileno);

    }

    printf("\n\nThe Information has been added");
    printf("\n\nNAME        AGE     ADDRESS     MOBILE NUMBER");

    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s        %.0lf       %s      %.0lf",x.name,x.age,x.address,x.mobileno);
    }
    getch();
}
```

I have a problem in displaying the 5 different record. How do I display the five records in one printf?

Comment: Do not store mobile numbers as double. Doubles are imprecise and also require leading 0 in some countries.

Comment: Your core problem is that you have a single `struct rec` variable `x` that you are attempting to store 5 different values in, and expect to be able to retrieve all five of them later. Variables can only store one value. You need to learn about and use arrays.

Comment: What should i use? or do in the mobile numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a collection of structures to save the data into, currently you're just overwriting the data each time. There are a lot of ways to do this, but you could do something like use a static array, for example:

```
struct rec {
    char name[100],address[100];
    double age,mobileno;
};

int main() {
    struct rec records[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)        // <-- note this is 0 to 4, not 1 to 5
    {
        printf("Enter Your Name: ");
        scanf("%s",records[i].name);  // <-- don't add the & for the string input
```

Same for the `printf()` further down:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("Name is: %s\n", records[i].name);
```

Comment: Just a note that, while this particular array size may work ok, in general, allocating large arrays of large structs as local variables is not considered very good practice, and may in fact cause failures that are a bit hard to determine the cause of down the road. In this case each `struct rec` is on the order of ~220 bytes, and so 5 of them is only ~1100 bytes, but your stack has a limited size...